# On mouse hover pop-up Chinese dictionary browser extension alternative to Perapera

Tags: web-browser

Perapera development stopped in 2021 according to: https://www.perapera.org/plugins/ and since browsers don't have stable extension APIs, it soon stopped working, e.g. you can't install it anymore on Chromium 88.

Are there any alternatives, hopefully open source?

https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/laz6i3/what_happened_to_perapera_on_chrome/ mentions [Zhongwen](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zhongwen-chinese-english/kkmlkkjojmombglmlpbpapmhcaljjkde?hl=en) which is open source: https://github.com/cschiller/zhongwen I'm going to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

[Zhongwen](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zhongwen-chinese-english/kkmlkkjojmombglmlpbpapmhcaljjkde?hl=en) is open source: https://github.com/cschiller/zhongwen and worked on Chromium 88 Ubuntu 20.10 on my first attempt. I've been using it since I wrote this answer, and had no problems so far, great work!!!

[image]